# Creating a function that iterates over date in dataframe in search for the most recent values and then save them to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks something like this:

| Year | Country | variable1 | variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | US | 3 | 2 |
| 2015 | UK | ... | 2 |
| 2015 | DE | ... | 2 |
| 2015 | ZM | 3 | ... |
| 2016 | US | 4 | 5 |
| 2016 | UK | 5 | 6 |
| 2016 | DE | ... | 2 |
| 2016 | ZM | ... | ... |

And I would like to have only the most recent value of variables, but the issue is that the data is not always avaible. So the function would need to iterate over countries and then over years to search for the most recent value and also return the date. So the new dataframe would look like this:

| Country | variable1 | variable1 year | variable 2 | variable2 year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 4 | 2016 | 5 | 2016 |
| UK | 5 | 2016 | 6 | 2016 |
| DE | ... | ... | 2 | 2016 |
| ZM | 3 | 2015 | ... | ... |

Is there a way to just create a function that does this (preferably it should also iterate through the rows, cause there are many more than 2 variables) or do I need to do some operations on the original dataframe first?

Comment: is variable number independ?  so you could have a line that had the same variable in the first column and the second column like variable1  2 and variable2 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this the same way one would do it in excel: split, sort, drop duplicates and join the data.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Year=[2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2000],
    Country= "US UK DE ZM US UK DE ZM US".split(),
    variable1=[3, None, None, 3, 4, 5, None, None, 5000],
    variable2=[2,2,2,None,5,6,2,None,5000],
))

def get_var_df(dframe, var):
    return dframe[["Year","Country",var]].dropna().sort_values(
        'Year').drop_duplicates('Country', keep='last').rename(
            columns={"Year":f"{var} year"})

new_df = get_var_df(df,"variable1").merge(
    get_var_df(df,"variable2"), on="Country", how="outer")[[
        "Country", "variable1", "variable1 year",
        "variable2", "variable2 year"]].sort_values(
            ["variable2 year", "variable1 year"])

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  Country  variable1  variable1 year  variable2  variable2 year
1      US        4.0          2016.0        5.0          2016.0
2      UK        5.0          2016.0        6.0          2016.0
3      DE        NaN             NaN        2.0          2016.0
0      ZM        3.0          2015.0        NaN             NaN
```